# Debugging Ruby-Code with Aptana

Tags: ruby, aptana, aptana3

I'm trying to debug a ruby program using Aptana Studio 3.

When I start the deubgging, I get the following message in the console:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/debugger-ide-0.0.2/lib/ruby-debug/command.rb:32: warning: already initialized constant DEF_OPTIONS
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/debugger-ide-0.0.2/bin/rdebug-ide:56: warning: already initialized constant ARGV
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.9) listens on :58828
Exception in DebugThread loop: undefined method `control' for Debugger::SkipCommand:Class
```

I'm using Stand-Alone Aptana-Studio 3.4.0 on Linux Mint 14 ("Nadia").